# Connect to kubeapi server on host connected on Zerotier

Tags: networking, kubernetes

My problem is, I have provisioned [DeepOps](https://github.com/NVIDIA/deepops/tree/master/docs/k8s-cluster) Kubernetes over a network using my laptop as a controller machine with Zerotier as the network. On my physical network (lan) the host address is 192.168.50.8 On zerotier the network the host address is 172.22.93.12. I have both laptop and k8s host on physical network and Zerotier network. SSH is obviously enabled from laptop to node and the ufw firewall rules on node are set to only allow A) http/https and B) ssh from Zerotier subnets. The (single node) cluster was provisioned and seems to be running, but I don't have kubectl access meaning I'm dead in the water. The server field in kubeconfig is https://192.168.50.8:6443 but I get an error when I try either address:

`The connection to the server 192.168.50.8:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`

So far my idea is to use [layer 2 bridging](https://zerotier.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SD/pages/7471125/Layer+2+Bridging+of+Ethernet+and+ZeroTier+Networks+on+Linux) on the Zerotier network to route traffic to the physical network but I would need a extra NIC on the host and my connection to the router is over wifi. I know this isn't normally how you do these things but I'm at the beginning of a homelab and any help would be greatly appreciated.